# Ошибка сегментирования (Linux, C)

Tags: linux, c, ubuntu

Всем привет. При попытке запустить код, приведенный ниже, выводит следующую ошибку: `Ошибка сегментирования (стек памяти сброшен на диск)`
Пытался провести отладку через gdb, но там код также не запускался, и gdb выдавал следующую ошибку:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
__strcpy_sse2_unaligned () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strcpy-sse2-unaligned.S:298
298 ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strcpy-sse2-unaligned.S: Нет такого файла или каталога.
```

Что делать?

Код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include "hacking.h" // There is the description of "fatal(...)"

#define FILENAME "/home/totalboy/notes"

int print_notes(int, int, char*); // The function of showing notes
int find_user_note(int, int); // Finding in the file for notes of user
int search_note(char*, char*); // The function of finding by keywords
void fatal(char*); // Handler critical errors

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  int userid, printing = 1, fd; // fd is description of out file
  char searchstring[100] = { 0 };

  if(argv > 1) // If there are arguments
    strcpy(searchstring, argv[1]); // Then it's the string of finding
  else
    searchstring[0] = 0; // Else the string of finding is empty

  userid = getuid();

  fd = open(FILENAME, O_RDONLY); // Opening the file for only reading
  if(fd == -1)
    fatal("в функции main() при открытии файла на чтение");

  while(printing)
    printing = print_notes(fd, userid, searchstring);

  printf("------------[конец данных, касающихся заметки]------------");
  close(fd);
}

// The function of showing notes for certain uid, coinciding with the optional
// finding string
// In the end of file will be returning 0
// If there are more arguments it will be returning 1
int print_notes(int fd, int uid, char* searchstring) {
  int note_length = find_user_note(fd, uid);
  char byte = 0, note_buffer[100] = { 0 };

  if(note_length == -1) // If it's the end of the file
    return 0; // returning 0

  read(fd, note_buffer, note_length); // Reading the data of notes
  note_buffer[note_length] = 0; // The finishing of the string

  // If the finding string is discovered
  if(search_note(note_buffer, searchstring))
    printf(note_buffer); // Showing it

  return 1;
}

// The function of finding the next note for specified userID;
// It will be returning 1 with getting the end of the file
// In another way it will be returning the length of the discovered note
int find_user_note(int fd, int user_uid) {
  int note_uid = -1;
  unsigned char byte = NULL;
  int length = 0;

  while(note_uid != user_uid) { // While it's not the note for user_uid
    if(read(fd, &note_uid, 4) != 4) // Reading the data of uid
      return -1; // If 4 bytes aren't read it will be returning the file's end
    if(read(fd, &byte, 1) != 1) // Reading the symbol of the string's translate
      return -1;

    byte = length = 0;
    while(byte != '\n') { // Defining the bytes' count away from the string's end
      if(read(fd, &byte, 1) != 1) // Reading the one byte
        return -1; // If one's not read it will be returning the end of the file
      length++;
    }
  }

  lseek(fd, length * -1, SEEK_CUR); // Moving the reading position to length bytes

  printf("[DEBUG] обнаружена заметка длинной %d байтов для id %d\n", length,
    note_uid);

  return length;
}

// The function of finding notes by keyword
// It will be returning 1 if it discovered the coincidence
// It will be returning 0 in another way
int search_note(char* note, char* keyword) {
  int match = 0;
  int keyword_length = strlen(keyword);

  if(keyword_length == 0) // If there is no finding string,
    return 1;             // It always is the coincidence

  for(int i = 0; i < strlen(note); i++) { // THe note's byte-by-byte view
    if(note[i] == keyword[match]) // If the bite coincides with the keyword
      match++; // it prepares to check next byte
    else { // In another way
      if(note[i] == keyword[0]) // IF the byte coincides with the first byte of the keyword
        match = 1; // It starts the calculaction with 1
      else
        match = 0; // In another way it is 0
    }
    if(match == keyword_length) // If there is the full coincidence
      return 1; // Returning the code 1
  }
  return 0; // Returning the code 0
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Даже по сообщению о segfault можно догадаться, что падение происходит в функции `strcpy`. А вызов `strcpy` у вас в коде всего один

```
if(argv > 1) // If there are arguments
  strcpy(searchstring, argv[1]); // Then it's the string of finding
```

Почему с `1` вдруг сравнивается `argv`, а не `argc`?

Язык С запрещает сравнения между указателями и целыми числами. Ваш компилятор, без сомнения, сказал вам о этом. Вы просто проигнорировали диагностические сообщения компилятора?

Comment: Господи, какая тупая ошибка. Спасибо)

Comment: GCC, на удивление, ни слова про это не сказал

Comment: @qucals: Не может быть. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1036a618d55aab6c

Comment: https://ibb.co/G5xkT14

Comment: @qucals: Ну так может у вас там GCC вручную настроен на подавление определенной диагностики? На godbolt мне не удалось найти версии GCC, которая бы не выдавала такой диагностики по умолчанию.